# Comparision with grund truth image

Tags: matlab, image-processing, comparison, feature-detection

I am currently working on object detection.I have obtained the co-ordinates of the object in the image.I am also having the ground truth (original) co-ordinates of the objects in the  image.Now i want to compare the obtained co-ordinates with the original one.So is there any method for doing that..or any method for calculating detection accuracy..thanks in advance..

Comment: L2 (Euclidean) distance?

Comment: As per your suggestion i found the L2 distance from Wikipedia..In the Euclidean plane, if p = (p1, p2) and q = (q1, q2) then the distance is given by 
    d(p,q)=sqrt{(p_1-q_1)^2 + (p_2-q_2)^2}. . i want to know that  whether p1 and p2 are x and y co-ordinates of p or p contains the two x co-ordinates and q contains the two y co-ordinates...

Comment: The first one. p1, p2. is x,y

Comment: @chappjc ok..thanks for your valuable suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is multiple ways to achieve that depending on your needs, but in our case we use the Modified [Hausdorff Distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_distance). You can find a working matlab code on filexchange [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/29968-modified-hausdorff-distance). It is fairly easy to use. The function takes the 2 point sets and returns a distance.

Another method, faster but a less robust is the quotient of similarity defined as 2*pixels included in both object, over the addition of the total number of pixels in each object.

```
2*N(a,b) / ( N(a)+N(b) )
```

where N is the number of pixels.

EDIT for graphical comparison:

We use the fileexchange rendering function [sc](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/16233-sc-powerful-image-rendering). You can easily create a mask with 2 binary images. You can create a new image by adding your objects over your ground truth. You can apply the mask  with a different color, so the differences will stand out.

Comment: N(a) and N(b) are the no of pixels in imagea and imageb.But what is N(a,b)?

Answer (score 1):

People in object detection field ([see Pedro Felzenszwalb page](http://cs.brown.edu/~pff/)) typically use bounding box overlap to measure detection accuracy (position is not everything since there is also an extent). The formula is

```
overlap = area(bbox1 & bbox2)/area(bbox1 | bbox2)
```

where & means intersection and | means union. Note that this doesn't require mapping pixels in two objects (which may not be well defined) as another answer suggested. Bounding box can be easily calculated if its axes are aligned with the coordinate system as min-max coordinates. For rotated bounding boxes you can [fit an ellipse](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=fit%20ellipse#cv.FitEllipse2) and use rotatedRect class:

```
RotatedRect rect;
vector<Point2f> pts; // you have to fill out pts
...
rect = fitEllipse(pts);
```

Finally if you need to know if a given point is inside of a polygon you can use a [pointPolygonTest](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=pointpolygontest#cv.PointPolygonTest).